# Fibonacci proof with a language

Tags: computer-science

The proof I am working toward achieving is as follows:

[image]

I know this can be proven using induction, and in doing so, I will need to:

- show when n = 2, F₂ = G₀; when n = 3, F₃ = G₁; if $F_{n -1} = G_{n - 3}$, then $F_n = G_{n - 2}$ for any $n > 2$
- $G_{n - 3} = F_{n - 1}$; $G_{n - 4} = F_{n - 2}$; $G_{n - 2} = G_{n - 3} + G_{n - 4}$; $F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2} = F_n$
- $F_n = G_{n - 2}$ for all $n > 2$

Comment: The question is weirdly-phrased; it might help to 'flip variables' and think of what you're trying to do as being to prove that (taking $k=n-2$ and reversing the equality) $G_k=F_{k+2}$ for all $k$.  You already know the behavior of the sequence $\{F_i\}$, so you can treat it as a given; what you want to show is that your sequence $\{G_i\}$ is similar.

Comment: (And a broad sense as to how to do that: suppose the last character of a particular string (of length $n$) satisfying your condition is '$b$'; what does the rest of the string look like?  Suppose instead that the last character of the string is '$a$'; what does the rest of the string look like then?)

Answer (score 0):

Let's just show that combinatorically,

Let $G_n$ be that number, let's look on a word that is legal first letter:
- if it's an 'a' then the next letter must be 'b' and the remainder is a legal word with $n-2$ letters - $G_{n-2}$
- if it's a 'b' then the remainder is a legal word with length $n-1$ - $G_{n-1}$

Therefore $$G_n = G_{n-1} + G_{n-2}$$

With initial conditions:
$G_0 = 1$ - the empty word is legal of length zero, and $G_1 = 2$, since all the words of length 2 are legal.
Since $G_0 = F_2$ and $G_1 = F_3$ we get exactly what we want.